# Typing Animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am looking to animate text in iOS Swift like they have in Microsoft Powerpoint. Here is a link of what I am trying to do in Swift:

http://www.ellenfinkelstein.com/pptblog/text-animation-techniques/

(The one I am looking at is the typewriter effect they have in Example 3 in the website)

I am unable to seem to find a method of how to do this.

Any help is appreciated :)

---

***Edit:*** Currently I am using a naive approach and fading them in one by one. But it is SIGABRTing on me

**ViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var hash1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var i: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var n: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var c: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var l: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var u: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var d: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var e: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var leftarrow: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var s: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var t: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var d1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var i1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var o: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dot: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var h: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var rightarrow: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hash1.alpha = 0
    self.i.alpha = 0
    self.n.alpha = 0
    self.c.alpha = 0
    self.l.alpha = 0
    self.u.alpha = 0
    self.d.alpha = 0
    self.e.alpha = 0
    self.leftarrow.alpha = 0
    self.s.alpha = 0
    self.t.alpha = 0
    self.d1.alpha = 0
    self.i1.alpha = 0
    self.o.alpha = 0
    self.dot.alpha = 0
    self.h.alpha = 0
    self.rightarrow.alpha = 0

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in self.hash1.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in self.i.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in self.n.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in self.c.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in self.l.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, animations: { () -> Void in self.u.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, animations: { () -> Void in self.d.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, animations: { () -> Void in self.e.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, animations: { () -> Void in self.leftarrow.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in self.s.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.1, animations: { () -> Void in self.t.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.2, animations: { () -> Void in self.d1.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.3, animations: { () -> Void in self.i.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.4, animations: { () -> Void in self.o.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: { () -> Void in self.dot.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.6, animations: { () -> Void in self.h.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.7, animations: { () -> Void in self.rightarrow.alpha = 1.0})

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

I feel that there has to be a better way (or even a working way) to approach this.

Comment: If you show an attempt at some code you are more likely to get some help.

Comment: Use UIView animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive way to do it would be to simply set up a repeating timer.
Have the timer increment an Int instance variable starting at zero.

Use the Int value to take a substring of your message and install it in a label. When the index reaches the full length of your message, kill the timer (or reset the Int variable to zero if you want the text to go away and start drawing again.)